# testing passport-facebook auth in development

Tags: node.js, oauth, passport.js, passport-facebook

I'd like to keep my clientId and secret for Facebook in a secure location and not commit to github or share with the entire dev team.

Do most folks create dev applications on facebook?

Answer (score 1):

Well,you could set them up as environment variables.In the development machine from the shell prompt you can do the below

```
$ export clientID="xxxxx"
$ export clientSecret="xxxxx"
```

In your node.js code these 2 variables will now be available as common variables under

```
process.env.ClientID
process.env.ClientSecret
```